# How to make a create account page outside of a login page

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

In Oracle apex i currently have a login page and authentication scheme based on the provided login page that apex automatically generates when you make a new application. However, i want users to be able to make an account  so i inserted a create button on the login page that redirects to a form that lets them make an account. The problem is that this create account form is inside the application so a user needs to log in first before they can create an account which makes no practical sense. I want this create account form to be outside of my application so that users can create an account and then use it to log in.

Im not too sure what to do here since every form and page seems to only be accessible once you log in yet i want a create account form before you log in. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try to go to page properties and make it public. go to the section "security" >> "authentication" >> "page is public"

Answer (score 1):

Your "Create account" page needs to be public, to do this you have to:

Got to your page, **Security** > **Authentication** > Change "**Page Requires Authentication**" to "**Page is Public**"